# Silverlight Cancel bubbling mouse move event

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7

I placed a bing maps control in a windows phone 7 pivot viewer control. If I move the map left or right, the pivot wants to switch views.

How can I prevent this event to bubble up to the pivot control?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both the `Maps` control and the `Pivot` control are both interested in gestures, so a left or right "flick" results in the `Pivot` changing the selected item. It is actually not reccomended to put a `Maps` control in a `Pivot` (or `Panorama` for this very reason). However, if this is the best approach for your application, then there is a solution in this blog post: [WP7 the Pivot and Bing Map dilemma](http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111).